# How do I access child routeParams from a parent component?

Tags: angular

I have a "projects" page where I am trying to access wether or not you are looking at the list of items or at a single item, but without using a child component.

Consider:

App Router Config

```
{ path: '/projects/...', component: ProjectCmp, name: 'Projects' },
```

Then the project component:

```
    { path: '/', useAsDefault:true,component: ProjectDashboardCmp, name: 'List' },
    { path: '/:id/', component: ProjectDashboardCmp, name: 'Dashboard' },
    { path: '/:id/shows', component: ShowCmp, name: 'Shows' },
```

How do I get the "id" that is passed to the "Dashboard" Route? It isn't a param of this component so I can't access it without the child kicking it up or a service.

example, in the projects component:

```
constructor(public params: RouteParams) {
    this.projectId = params.get('id');
    console.log("The project Id is:",this.projectId); 
    //The Project Id is:null
```

But inside the projectDashboardCmp it works as expected.

The issue is I do something like:

```
<router-outlet *ngIf="!this.projectId"></router-outlet>
```

In the project component so it doesn't ever load the child routes and just dies...

Comment: Why hide the `router-outlet`? Why not simply allow it to be empty? Need more information on your intentions before I can answer.

Comment: So what I'm doing is having a set of material design cards in a list. Imagine a masonry type grid. When you select a project the page "moves" over to that card and it becomes the sidebar. It does this by the sidebar and router outlet being hidden until needed. Because it needs to be "on top" the list of projects cant be in the same outlet. I was hiding the outlet with a NgIf

Comment: So this is purely for holding off navigation until an animation has completed?

Comment: The original intent yes. I of course have worked around it with just hiding it and using a service to communicate between components but there are other cases where I think knowing how to do it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is interested in how to access child routes params - Here is the solution (Angular 4.0):

```js
// Inside ngOnInit() method of a parent component
this.route.children[0].params
    .subscribe((childParams: Params) => this.projectId = +childParams['id']);
```

NOTE: `this.route.children` can have multiple child routes. In my case - it was only one, so I selected it with `[0]`.

Overall, I wouldn't recommend to use this approach, unless you have no other choice